# ExecJS Error when pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, execjs

I have a rails app that I'm trying to push heroku but it fails each time with this message:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 14023, col: 0, pos: 385975)
```

as well as some JS parsing errors. I have no idea where to even look for this error, as there's no file name given! I'm wondering if it's an issue with my application.js file, which is:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Also, I have a .coffee file for every js file I have, but I only have an application.js file, not an application.coffee file. Do I need one?

Also, for what it's worth, I get this error after running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

before trying push to heroku.

AND, in my config/environments/production file, I changed:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Please help!!

Full result when I run git push heroku master:

```
    rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 14023, col: 0, pos: 385975)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:11948)
    at js_error (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:12167)
    at croak (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:22038)
    at token_error (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:22175)
    at unexpected (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:22263)
    at block_ (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:28063)
    at /private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:27686
    at function_ (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:27782)
    at expr_atom (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3623:31068)
    at maybe_unary (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3624:1752)
    at expr_ops (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3624:2523)
    at maybe_conditional (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3624:2615)
    at maybe_assign (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3624:3058)
    at expression (/private/var/folders/0f/gkfrtx592rg1vvlngny3pvfw0000gn/T/execjs20170110-43579-1j8a3cpjs:3624:3384)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
block_ ((execjs):3623:28063)
(execjs):3623:27686
function_ ((execjs):3623:27782)
expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31068)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
expr_ops ((execjs):3624:2523)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):3624:2615)
maybe_assign ((execjs):3624:3058)
expression ((execjs):3624:3384)
/Users/lisabuch/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/lisabuch/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
buchoroney [master] :> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 261, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (246/246), done.
Writing objects: 100% (261/261), 80.90 MiB | 1.69 MiB/s, done.
Total 261 (delta 132), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 11.3.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using rack 1.6.5
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using coderay 1.1.1
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
remote:        Using thor 0.19.4
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Using high_voltage 3.0.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Using pg 0.19.0
remote:        Using slop 3.6.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Using rdoc 4.3.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.5.3
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.4
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using pry 0.10.4
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.6
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using pry-rails 0.3.4
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.6
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.6.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.6
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.6
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.6
remote:        Using railties 4.2.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.6
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 55 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (2.49s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing turbolinks (5.0.1)
remote:        Removing turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
remote:        Removing sass-rails (5.0.6)
remote:        Removing tilt (2.0.5)
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.664376 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/alpaca-df4ffb199b8c9840fad0e7e0bce8cd8cefc72e22344c0a5f176afbee4f6a8769.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.667287 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/beer-4bac3a4ff9a53e5ed7780c3d1fbfad9abf5e5720d4507f18e51d0ce7ad294a09.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.669620 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/cam-c87079ad40acfa1664069bb7e4ea894db2ed282bfcfa724a84e0afa0e81d8569.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.672490 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/canoe-d8b8b614ded174cfda9ded8a38e0717ce413b1985ddc8ff9796ed17f69a47aed.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.674929 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/cow-608a748a0f233089233c8d10bcdb1283015ba3504ea24e6687f43544b21a413b.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.698746 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_005-547aa608ad73f0f08cf6d7ded8062849c432eb749587f9b4e4ec8b5af7ad0337.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.752823 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_009-33866f70c9a80c30121917bf67fc44cec9fdb2715f4d1accc525a3582f795acd.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.769483 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_027-01d142fd5a9cd6000331b161c7125c50c09c7f5afd087f76c09ed8828c1b382a.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.783824 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_033-57919df03b7ca690ee356c6a0344e9b4a3e7212f639e7a110ffc445364c04eb1.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.822990 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_038-b77b2874171caf15b3ccabf01c009f7aeb1d9c8519df7a16f2c5e6a3c3c4982a.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.860187 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_041-a9a6360d0ffcb73e96d71de04d48065e62d4fcea744c9e4cfdfa4783e4b73c98.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.893716 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_046-31666604ace314f441c85b55d80e88060ba0e75d789df5759e7815769a975eea.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:56.930575 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_056-69d36d0467dbe972e6564a455c72d5fac47994ac2c3c0affc301a491b4e069e3.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.018137 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_076-2-5ae4592685fcbc23bec11e7709a4b14223f924eae08956bc93837b3a6af4205b.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.048294 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_083-5f2a2b4a38a0e22ff06fb7385032f6e7dde5e426067149f083583cce25ac47d0.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.070724 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_110-2-754645bffd02aa512f8bc20a69df00bb9ee047707b825708ce9493d232a2f397.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.096807 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_122-2b6c44727d328c8e6c1cc1ea5d10ed1b4bb31962e2fbcf19808ee793d3576003.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.159980 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_137-111c1fa98392a48a0ade5594ce069eb7ce5050fc3cdd0fdf6db3bc51626445b0.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.164788 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_148-f33ee4abc8f9124559f7360b7bea0ca02e6a0f53de211022b00fd812e1d25d58.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.199334 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_153-18b8a425ef3a2d576a39109cf74e99deeff70a3d782d041ef8fa54e996622cd2.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.236982 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_161-c0e920e27eab1dfa87ddced6a3575656970aeb868d10755fe7987160ec2aec9e.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.275939 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/dave_lisa_167-e96fe77279ddeddee6cb31252989e7d94bc43c92a50c700fdbcecd736f778e61.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.288059 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/hamilton-8604a101dbd9140966dd27b31eb814f92b24f654dd4a2b101f3f3027b14ff6d1.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.374823 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/hero-b014eb100249b79821482d82d088aa79ea48a4b47724cfe37a89833b606cc131.ai
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.390492 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/hero-9eb57ee5fb893691023138931bab42ff95342fd0389c1af713a1db8f14065305.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.395194 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/hikersfll-c59462b036f36426b7fe9771b99b63764c50a9b87682113827e2a3425920b574.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.399108 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/kimballs-dcc133eb4f6e062e90e74739dde8e5fc57d1eff199e83314caeb9cebdae7f290.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.402917 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave1-606308b8824d6f27e5c4f75b5ec51c94cfa8744f6a764407977a4d76b64fe514.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.405918 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave10-20fa30db1c380aea8ed5d3811013cc225770d836eb4fec8e44817e3b8d8001e7.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.408969 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave11-269ddbd59bd80273229da49898e9b758ccf0b34f0967a80659530c432ea909f7.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.411399 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave12-e9ff5bb0e198bf38a8a2f1aec6b666b88146b4d8339389c24218fa2926c36e1a.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.413896 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave13-f98d6d4bbc7d643b4325a5816b042fba7e2fd2ef17943766264fb1fd850e6ca5.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.416221 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave14-e7f0d1011120522a87d0f2361670f02282484afb9dae5dcf2f01aed506f41845.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.418625 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave15-fb11b642966b37a9f20e35819f2439fcb3ad3447e0cee06fff4ea223647a9945.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.420933 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave16-02ac6041f124732cfd09a692d441ee9c19629dc3e8dd81f2d9b21a4a179e10d3.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.423633 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave18-0b62f7da231d69d9c0fb9590e61339822f100d29040a00a3fc02d84947fd8a91.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.426137 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave19-6951b2c7daa7753348aa634fcfe102fd41c32ab8640d6023c7d34b7dda187338.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.428679 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave2-37df1eaac9be0374473201127858be3808dbf547628f5db527ec344a53676fcd.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.431044 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave20-a6ad32180a92439757595342ba879f97c305ca3a311e647bb608e0d72c7257a4.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.433451 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave21-2c5563a5d8581f9c23554359f34227c8ecf927e9bbfa60777e7f661231fac50d.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.435760 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave22-9de7121d5861e6cb27c96aeb0a4e658b5e05ca378ba8305b62e4327e1501b2e2.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.438153 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave3-2b0157491b87626e065f9b29768e9a5f0c161b73d125eedf45aaf28424de0b42.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.440881 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave4-b8ff8eeb74b500943020ac96362fafe7ab72e4822fee0b50175c8edbbb6bece1.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.443190 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave5-9d77809062b3a5d3c08964f6b077b8478c3b9143c9555b2999e0d78ab920446f.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.445635 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave6-42e87aa80d804d7790b84181e30af4582b2f401dc6e4afe08ddb6469c24fb734.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.448011 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave7-63ccc9204063c316506d6845071a96cd76960270240b790cc25804fd6a80d12a.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.450691 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave8-bccd869c69444bc47581aaf64bf5e68765565d3b9316e16c531255208d02dfbd.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.453438 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/lisadave9-931ce7f441153253d63d6a4dafe66eac08024d05894ec91059dca172ff12b526.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.458226 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/map2-180dc2e10d2714614d6d1490558333df6c3636bf69e69902824c0944bde9670c.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.460749 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/point-4b0f49dae07c43320da2a3cbf304f43802d197e2aa3ed7623115131f28becfcb.png
remote:        I, [2017-01-11T04:11:57.462880 #399]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/public/assets/zola-logo-pride-d108e071e53520801701f2bf28688c7509d1bace56e907094c71116399cbe2ef.png
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 14023, col: 0, pos: 385975)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:11948)
remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:12167)
remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:22038)
remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:22175)
remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:22263)
remote:        at block_ (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:28063)
remote:        at ctor.body (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:27686)
remote:        at function_ (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:27782)
remote:        at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3623:31068)
remote:        at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3624:1752)
remote:        at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3624:2523)
remote:        at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3624:2615)
remote:        at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20170111-399-kkh7m3js:3624:3058)
remote:        new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3623:11948)
remote:        js_error ((execjs):3623:12167)
remote:        croak ((execjs):3623:22038)
remote:        token_error ((execjs):3623:22175)
remote:        unexpected ((execjs):3623:22263)
remote:        block_ ((execjs):3623:28063)
remote:        ctor.body ((execjs):3623:27686)
remote:        function_ ((execjs):3623:27782)
remote:        expr_atom ((execjs):3623:31068)
remote:        maybe_unary ((execjs):3624:1752)
remote:        expr_ops ((execjs):3624:2523)
remote:        maybe_conditional ((execjs):3624:2615)
remote:        maybe_assign ((execjs):3624:3058)
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:184:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:146:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_fe8ef243326ee2b905f4daf134cdd349/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to immense-basin-69611.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/immense-basin-69611.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-basin-69611.git'
```

Comment: Could you post more of the logs from heroku?

Comment: OK, updated my question.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working! I needed to run git add public/assets and commit that before pushing!

Comment: Take a look at here https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/521 and play around with line endings and file endings. Could be a file format issue. To me `eof` sounds like end of file. What editor are you using?

Comment: Nice, sometimes it's just not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment gem 'therubyracer' and run bundle and push the code to heroku.